# Represent indexes from matrices

Tags: matlab

I have 2 matrices U,V that represent all the coordinates for my rectangle.
I need to go over all the coordinates (u,v) and change the value of specific (u,v) coordinate in matrix T to 1 if v~=0, but I can't change (u,v) to integers, bc its matrix..
any idea?

```
M = [3,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40];

[U,V] = meshgrid (0:1:M(1)-1,0:1:M(1)-1);

T = -4*eye((M(1)^2));
W = -1*zeros(M(1),1);
if V~=0
    T(U,V)=1
```

Comment: In this code V will always be zero for the first row and nonzero all other rows. So you could simply use `T(2:end,:)=1`, however in the general case you could do `T(V~=0)=1`

Comment: You won't be able to change also when U==0. So, try this - `vind = U(:) & V(:); T(sub2ind(size(T),U(vind),V(vind)))=1;`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is to use matlab's extremely powerful logical indexing `T(V~=0)=1`